# initiating code for controls

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i want to know where to place an initiating code for controls placed on user interface such as a UIImageView placed on story board
since it will be automatticallt created when application runs ?

i tried to add an objective-c class of UIImageView and placed the code in an init method, then assigned that class the UIImageView
control that i placed on the story board but seems that didnt work ?

i know i made an example with image view but its a general question for all controls placed on user interface

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do and mean by "initiating code for controls" but the best bet is probably to subclass UIImageView and then make sure to make the object on the storyboard the type of the subclass.

Comment: I already did what you asked me to do, but below code didnt run in the sub class implementation file 
- (void) loadView
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

If the control is in the storyboard, then initWithCoder: is the init method that will be called when it's instantiated. So, the place to put initiation code is either in initWithCoder: or awakeFromNib.